# How can I identify a Youtube video URL for a lesson's video from FluentU?

Tags: self-learning

I'd like to track down a URL for a video for one of the lessons on FluentU.

What, if any, means exist to find out a video URL for a YouTube video used as a lesson video within FluentU?

Thanks,